# a problem on cauchy sequence under the continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
Pick out the true statements.
(a) $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.
(b) If $X$ is compact, then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.
(c) If $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ , then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.

---

to preserve Cauchy sequence $f$ need to be uniformly continuous.
(a) is not true. as example $f(x)=1/x$ and the sequence {$1/n$}
(b) true.as in compact set a continuous function becomes uniformly continuous.
(c) false by (a).

are my thinking correct or I am missing something because the given answer is (b) and (c)

Comment: c> $\mathbb R^n$ is complete so...

Comment: i did not understand. since $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ complete every Cauchy sequence is convergent.but i think the given condition is different

Comment: isnt the image of the sequence  $x_n$ in $\mathbb R^n$ cauchy in $\mathbb R$ ?  use the definition of Cauchy sequence

Comment: c is right, because continuous function is uniformly continuous on compact set.

Comment: @lee in c> where did the compact set come from?

Comment: The Cauchy sequence with it's limit point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning c): The counterexample $f(x) := \frac{1}{x}$ doesn't work, since you can't define it (as a continuous function) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but only on $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$.

Let $(x_n)_{n} \subseteq X := \mathbb{R}^n$ a Cauchy sequence. Since $X$ is complete, we have $x_n \to x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $f$ is (sequentially) continuous, we obtain $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, i.e. $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and in particular a Cauchy sequence.

**Remark**  This proves also b) (since a compact metric space $X$ is in particular complete).

Comment: any convergent sequence is cauchy?

Comment: @Panu In a metric space? Yes.